# No sound in Ubuntu 14.04, though Intel and Nvidia cards are detected

Tags: sound

I'm getting no sound on a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 14.04. Result of running `alsa-info` is [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=422ef359afc024b224d3d93584ad3d2816c4e45e).

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF114 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

I tried purge/reinstall of `pulseaudio` and `alsa-base` and removing `.config/pulse` and `.pulse-cookie`. Using headphones did not work either. What else can I try to fix this?

Sound works fine in Windows, so not a hardware issue.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Zanna As far as I remember I never did, but I also don't have access to the system anymore, and I think the hardware died on me at some point anyway. I raised a flag to close this question as offtopic, but it doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: Fag found and closing your question!  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

1. in a Terminal launch `alsamixer` and be sure that:

   - your **speaker** volume is above 0
   - and **Auto-mute** is Disabled

     [image: alsamixer]
2. Run an application making noise ( a web radio for example )
3. Open `pulseaudio`,

   - in the 1st tab set your application making noise to **Internal Audio** (something like that)
     [image: pulseaudio settings (in French)]
   - in the 3rd tab, set your **Internal Audio** to **Speaker** (even if they are marked as unavailable)
     [image: pulseaudio settings]
     and set this device as the default one by ticking the green icon
     [image: green icon with a tick]
   - in last tab, set your **Internal Audio** to **Stereo Duplex**
     [image: configuration options]
   - save these settings  for next session

     `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state store`
   - to be sure to get these settings, add this command in your starting application

     `alsactl --file ~/.config/asound.state restore`