# No sound in ubuntu 14.04, again!

Tags: 14.04, sound

I have done almost all the solutions that I could find!
i.e. reinstalling pulse-audio and alsa-base, playing around with alsamixer, etc. But couldn't make it work.

My audio card is "Integrated: Realtek ALC269Q High Definition Audio".

In System Setting > Sound, I see three drivers: HDMI/Display port, Speakers, Analog output. Non of them produce any sound. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04.

alsa-info output can be found [here](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=6350bab22b5c6bba9a9d197f5d0a2175c3c0f00a).
Please let me know if you need other logs, info...

P.S. There is another similar unanswered question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/460508/no-sound-in-ubuntu-14-04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure step by step (until step 4). After that the sound was back, but I heard a loud static noise. I fixed that by changing the mic volume settings with alsamixer.